# Protobuf use option GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_REFSTRUCT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to generate a .cs file from a proto file, however the generated file has code that my compiler does not support. I'm not able to upgrade compiler thus I've researched this option, though I'm not sure on how to transform my proto file using this option:

`GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_REFSTRUCT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE`

Details of the option can be found in this [link](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/7490).

Comment: (removed protobuf-net, as this is specific to the google protobuf implementation)

Answer (score 2):

Try either adding [`DefineConstants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#defineconstants) XML node to .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_REFSTRUCT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or passing it as parameter to build: `/p:DefineConstants="GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_REFSTRUCT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE"`